# kubernetes issue : Init:ErrImagePull

Tags: kubernetes

I have following critical issue on kubernetes.
From couple of days I'm fighting with images from docker issues.
I have one server with docker-ce and on another master-server on kubernetes.
I don't understant this issue because everything was working fine and last time I have issues wirth images on docker.

Images on docker are there, and from kubernetes I see below errors:

> Failed to pull image "busybox": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error
> response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http:
> TLS handshake timeout

and also issues with get image from docker: Error: ErrImagePull

> Back-off pulling image "busybox" Error: ImagePullBackOff

Can someone help me with that please ?

Comment: This sounds like an issue with the networking connectivity in your cluster, not anything you could fix with source code or YAML configuration.

Comment: Hello, David
Thanks for Your reply, is it possible that I could check if port is open from docker side in order to get image from kubernetes ? In yaml file I have settings: ImagePullPolicy - IfNotPresent

Comment: Check if you are able to docker using ```curl https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/``` it should say ``` {"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":null}]}``` if there are no networking issues